# Integrating Coldfusion and Pay360

Tags: php, coldfusion

Does anyone have any experience with integrating a Coldfusion website with Pay360? Basically, our online shop needs to direct the user to a payment screen on Pay360 using the hosted cashier.

The [documentation](https://docs.pay360.com/getting-started/submitting-requests/) is a bit vague but essentially we have to pass an API username and password, and JSON string to their request URL and they should return a response with a URL to a payment form. Should be straightforward using `cfhttp` but I get an error:

```
{
      "status"        : "FAILED"
    , "reasonCode"    : "exception.request.content"
    , "reasonMessage" : "Invalid request content: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)"
}
```

No one at Pay360 seems to be able to help. I've also tried using PHP (having only found one example on bronco.co.uk by doing a Google search) but that doesn't work for me either.

This is my code. If anyone can give any advice (or has a working CF or PHP script that could point me in the right direction) that would be great, thanks!

```
<cfset variables.username = "xxxxxx">
<cfset variables.password = "xxxxxx">
<cfset stFields = {
  "session": {
    "preAuthCallback": {
      "url": "http://www.example.com/callback/preAuth?status=SUSPEND",
      "format": "REST_XML"
    },
    "returnUrl": {
      "url": "http://www.example.com/transactionResult?MERCHANTREF=761585761585"
    }
  },
  "transaction": {
    "merchantReference": "761585761585",
    "money": {
      "amount": {
        "fixed": 100
      },
    "currency": "GBP"
    }
  },
  "customer": {
    "identity": {
      "merchantCustomerId": "1111111111111"
    },
    "details": {
      "name": "given1 Family1",
      "address": {
        "line1": "matched",
        "line2": "initialCustomer1AddresssLine2",
        "city": "initalCustomer1City",
        "region": "initalCustomer1Region",
        "postcode": "AVS111",
        "countryCode": "GBR"
      },
      "telephone": "0044111111111",
      "emailAddress": "initialCustomer1@example.com",
      "ipAddress": "1.1.1.1",
      "defaultCurrency": "GBP"
    }
  },
  "financialServices": {
    "dateOfBirth": "19870818",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "accountNumber": "123ABC",
    "postCode": "BS20"
  }
}>   

<cfhttp url="https://api.mite.pay360.com/hosted/rest/sessions/5309398/payments" method="post" username="#variables.username#" password="#variables.password#" result="httpResp" timeout="60">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <!--- failed attempt to pass username and password in the body
<cfhttpparam type="formField" name="username" value="#variables.username#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="password" value="#variables.password#">--->
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(stFields)#">
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#httpResp#"/>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for this API call?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Here is the link to their documentation. https://docs.pay360.com/getting-started/submitting-requests/

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as it contains a complete example, description of the error and link to the docs. Voting to reopen.

Comment: FWIW I created a test account and ran the code above and it worked fine. The only thing I changed was "username", "password" and the installation id, i.e. `5309398`

Comment: @SOS Thanks. Not sure why the question was closed either. So the above code worked fine for you and you got a valid response? Very strange. I guess that might point to it being an issue with the installation id given to me.

Comment: @DatapartnersInternet - Yes, the installation id I was given the response was `{"sessionId":"xxxxxx","redirectUrl":"https://secure.mite.pay360.com/hosted/xxxx/begin/xxxxx","status":"SUCCESS"}` and visiting the real url in a browser brings up a payment form. Unfortunately I couldn't test it with your installation as it returns `{"status":"FAILED","reasonCode":"exception.authenticationFailure.noPriv","reasonMessage":"Authorisation Failed"} `. Guess it's user specific.

Comment: @SOS thanks so much for your help with this. I managed to get it working in the end using a PHP script so I need to investigate what setup in my CF installation is preventing it from working (it appears to be something to do with the base64 encoding when passing username and password). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @DatapartnersInternet - You're welcome, glad you got something working! Tbh I don't think the encoding is the issue... The code uses the ["basic" authentication scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization#examples) (see [trycf.com example](https://trycf.com/gist/45a2ec6542676868883a7865efefcae9/lucee5?theme=monokai). Basic authentication hasn't changed in forever (: For grins I tested the code using a manually generated "Authorization" header too instead of the username/password attributes and it also worked fine (CF2018) so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: ... but I'd be curious to know what it is, so post back when you figure it out (: